# Best configuration for Ubuntu and Objective-C

Tags: 11.04, ipad, objective-c

Can someone post a proper Ubuntu Configuration for developing iPad's applications?

I need a good IDE and a guide on how to install any essential compilers etc.

Thanks

Comment: maybe wrong, but I think that the supported Apple SDK for iPad and iPhone runs on a Mac computer only?  My advice - stick to developing something that is more open such as Android.

Comment: Yes but I have a university project and I do not own a Mac

Comment: Mac OS X + XCode within VMWare instance running via VMWare Player or Workstation is your best bet then. If you want to mess with Mac OS X a bit you can try hackintosh. You'll need to buy Mac OS X in both cases though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developing Iphone and IPad applications is supported only if it is developed on a Mac.  This is especially true if you want your application to end up in the App-store.  A good explanation is given on [another stackoverflow site here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995252/apple-ios-ide-for-linux) which ties together your Objective-C question and writing for the IPad.

Apple, unusually perhaps, have an excellent [IDE and development tools](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) which they give away for free.

I would either buy a used Mac, or (if you have a license) - install a virtualised OS-X in VMWare etc.

`KDevelop` does have some Objective C patches - but it doesnt look like it is actively supported.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @fossfreedom . The only application I know is [dragonFireSDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/) , to create iPad and iPhone applications in Windows only.

I also asked for alternative in [Ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/search.php?searchid=82252806) long time ago, but I didn't find anything.